# MySQL stored procedure with transaction syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have actually moved to MySQL from SQL Server and it looks like the SQL syntax is quite different, I'm having hard time to complete creating the below stored procedure as I'm get different kind of errors. this is my first time posting on Stackoverflow, apologies if the formatting is not friendly. Thanks in advance.

#### 1- DECLARE is not valid at this position, Excepting EOF, ';'

#### 2- SET is not valid at this position, Excepting EOF, ';'

#### 3- COMMIT is not valid at this position, Excepting EOF, ';'

```
    DELIMITER //
   
    CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCustomer(IN email VARCHAR(100),IN pass VARCHAR(128),IN phoneNumber VARCHAR(12),IN gender INT,IN birthday DATE)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE last_user_inserted INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK; 
     RESIGNAL;
    END;
  
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO users (emailAddress,passwordHash,phoneNumber) VALUES(email,pass,phoneNumber)

     SET last_user_inserted = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO customers (user_id,gender,birthday) VALUES (last_user_id,gender, birthday)
  
      COMMIT;

     END;

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: but those first 3 lines must be commented, right?

Comment: Yup, they are not inside the code block.

Comment: I have edited it so that people don't get confused and moved it to the top.

Comment: In mysql EVERY statement needs to be terminated your inserts aren't and the end; should be end //

Comment: Thanks Javier, P.Salmon still not working unfortunately :(

Comment: 'Not working' isn't useful if you have an error message publish it in full, if it syntaxes but does not do what you want publish sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @p.salmon, here you go mate ---  11:40:15 CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCustomer(IN email VARCHAR(100),IN pass VARCHAR(128),IN phoneNumber VARCHAR(12),IN gender INT,IN birthday DATE) BEGIN DECLARE last_user_inserted INT DEFAULT 0 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 0.00045 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @P.Salmon, worked just fine.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCustomer(IN email VARCHAR(100),IN passVARCHAR(128),IN phoneNumber VARCHAR(12),IN gender INT,IN birthday DATE)
BEGIN

DECLARE last_user_inserted INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
ROLLBACK; 
 RESIGNAL;
 END;

  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO users (emailAddress,passwordHash,phoneNumber) VALUES(email,pass,phoneNumber);

 SET last_user_inserted = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO customer (user_id,gender,birthday) VALUES (last_user_id,gender, birthday);

  COMMIT;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```